# Firefox extension haven't installed using window registry installation

Tags: firefox, installation

I have followed the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) [MDC - Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry], but haven't been able to get Firefox to automatically install my extension when I restart it.

I have created key and set id and path of my extension. But nothing happen when i restart my firefox. attached screen shot about windows registry installation.

If any one have idea about this issues. Kindly suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Vasanthi

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable extensions.logging.enabled in about:config.
2. Exit Firefox and delete extensions.cache from your Firefox profile folder.
3. Start a command prompt and "SET NO_EM_RESTART=1"
4. Start Firefox from this command prompt

The error console should now contain a log of where Firefox found extensions, see if your registry one is listed and if it lists any problems when looking at it.

If it isn't listed at all then it is likely that you have put the registry entry in the wrong place or in the wrong format.